# Good solution for dynamic categories of items in database

Tags: mysql, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I am going to build a new database in MySQL and want to have the correct aim from the start. I will have a table with items and will then want to sort these by categories. My problem is that I want the categories to be dynamic.

If I would know the categories I'd build it something like this:

> **items-table**
>   id
>   category1_id
>   category2_id
>   title
>
> **categories1-table**
>   id
>   title
>
> **categories2-table**
>   id
>   title

But again, I want to be able to put as many different categories in there as I please on-the-fly, and also I want to be able to work with these different categories in my querys in conditions and orders. Is this even possible or do I have to make the categories solid in my database?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create three tables for that....

(1) tblItem :

```
  fields:
            itemId  (PK)
            itemName
            etc..
```

(2) tblCategory :

```
  fields:
            categoryId  (PK)
            categoryName
            etc..
```

(3) tblItemCategory :

```
  fields:
            itemId  (FK)
            categoryId  (FK)
```

Comment: Thank you for that @Sevak I added a fourth table to handle category groups. What is (FK) and (PK) btw?

Comment: PK= Primary key; FK= Foreign Key (=Primary key of a referenced table).

Answer (score 1):

I'm a fan of using a single "categories" table, and having a `parent_id` field to reference any other category in the table.

This allows you to have threaded categories all in a single table... your "Category Groups" would just be any category row that doesn't have data in it's parent_id field.

Example data

```
id    name          parent_id    category_count
1     appliances    null         1
2     dogs          null         1
3     couch         1            0
4     pitbull       2            0
5     games         null         0
//...
```

Basically, 'Category' is related to itself - here's the model associations:
(reference: the [3rd code example here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#multiple-relations-to-the-same-model) in the [CakePHP book](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/contents.html))

```
class Category extends AppModel {

    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Parent' => array(
            'className' => 'Category',
            'foreignKey' => 'parent_id',
            'counterCache' => true
        )
    );

    public $hasMany = array(
        'Children' => array(
            'className' => 'Category',
            'foreignKey' => 'parent_id'
        )
    );

    //...
}

class Item extends AppModel {

    public $belongsTo = array('Category');

    //...

}
```

You could also do `Item hasAndBelongsToMany Category` instead of `belongsTo` if you'd rather - just depends on your setup.

---

**Additional Info:**

**CounterCache:**  For more information on CakePHP's counterCache, [go here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#belongsto).

**find->threaded:**  Using this method, you can easily get the nested data via CakePHP's find->threaded ([click here for more info about this](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#find-threaded))

Comment: But doing like this, I lose the possibility of grouping on a category_group right? Like if I want to do 'fields' => 'COUNT(Category.id) AS category_count', 'group' => 'CategoryGroup.id'.

Comment: Not only shouldn't it limit you at all, but what you're talking about is actually built-in to CakePHP.   I've edited the answer above to include `counterCache` - this automatically keeps a count of any categories that are within a specific category (tested it just now to verify it works - and it does).  So... if you add another category to 'dogs', then the field 'category_count' in the 'dogs' row will be incremented.  It will also update the number anytime anything is deleted... basically, it takes care of it all for you.

Comment: I've also added a bit of info and a link to CakePHP's `find->threaded`, which I think you'll like.

Comment: Actually the counting of rows was a bit of a bad example on my part, what if I want to count something else, like a decimal value in the adjacent table like "SUM(items.amount) AS amount", "group" => "categoryGroup.id". I would guess this doesn't work in the query?

Comment: It would work just fine - every category still has an ID just like any other setup.

Comment: I don't really think so since Couch is beneath Appliances so if you group on categorys and I want to group on appliances and thus on couch and it's siblings under appliances, this wont work in the query.

Comment: And how would that differ from the accepted answer?  The only difference is that my example allows the flexibility of having child/parent categories, and that one doesn't.  (and what you're asking is certainly possible - if you'd like details on HOW, just post it as a question).  It's not a big deal - just giving you the heads up that when 6 months from now you decide you want nested categories, just come back here and find this answer ;)  (it works fine without nesting the categories too btw)

Comment: I agree with you that your solution is the best way to go with nested categories, however I know allready that I only want one level of categories. Say that we have Categories (id,title), CategoryItems (id,category_id,title) and Items (id,title,category_item_id,amount). Now in the find of cakePHP I can type 'fields' => 'SUM(Item.amount) AS amount', 'group' => 'Category.id' and will get the total amount of all items under a certain category.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is use many-to-many relations

Something like tahat:

```
**items**
id
title

**categories**
id
title

**items_categories**
item_id
category_id
```